Can I avoid loop in a loop and DMLs within the loop for this in a FLOW?
We have a requirement that I am trying to achieve with the help of a record-triggered flow. Here are the details of the requirement:
We have two record types in Opportunities: a Parent Record Type and a Child Record Type. One Parent Opportunity can have one or more Child Opportunities. Additionally, one Parent can have one or more Opportunity Line Items.
Whenever an Opportunity Line Item is created or updated on the Parent Opportunity, all the line items from the Parent must be copied to the Child Opportunities if there is no matching Product or line item. If the triggering line item on the Parent Opportunity matches one on a Child Opportunity, the corresponding line item on the Child must be updated.
In the flow I developed, I ended up using a loop within a loop because I needed to fetch all the Child Opportunities one by one, and for each Child Opportunity, I had to fetch the Parent Opportunity's line items one by one as well. This approach resulted in performing DML operations within the loop.
Is there an alternative way to avoid having a loop within a loop and performing DML operations inside the loop for this requirement? Any help is much appreciated.
Here is the summary of my flow. In my flow, PCB is the parent opportunity and Bid is the child opportunity. In the flow, my triggering condition is Opportunity Product ( Parent Opportunity ) is created or updated.
If there is a matching Product then update the line item wit the correct price and there is no line item found at the child opportunity then create the line item.





Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour].  That is a cumbersome data model.  You could create a self-lookup field on Opportunity Product to link the child line items to the parent line items, and thus simplify some of the flow.  But changing the business process and eliminating the  child opps would make things much easier.

Thanks for your reply. Yes, I am trying for an alternate solution now. I want to know is there a way we can get opportunity IDs stored in a text collection variable , separately into a single text variable. For ex: if I get "[006cX000003GSDuQAO,006cX000007BrFeQAK]" like this in a text collection variable using a loop. After the loop , is there way from the text collection var, "[006cX000003GSDuQAO,006cX000007BrFeQAK]", into a single text var OpportunityId1:006cX000003GSDuQAO and OpportunityId2: 006cX000007BrFeQAK ?
